# Find all partitions from a list of subsets

Tags: algorithm, subset, data-partitioning

Given a list of specific subsets like

```
S = [ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {1}, {2, 3}, {4}, {3} ]
```

and a "universe" set like

```
U = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

what elegant and simple algorithm can be used to find all the possible partitions of U made of sets from S? With this example, such partitions include

```
{1, 2} {3, 4}
{1, 2} {3} {4}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Split the problem into two smaller problems based on whether the first element is used or not:

- Partition using `{1,2}` and any of the the remaining sets.
- Partition without using `{1,2}` but using any of the the remaining sets.

These two options cover all possibilities.

- The first is solved by partitioning `{3,4}` using only `[ {3, 4}, {1}, {2, 3}, {4}, {3} ]`.
- The second is solved by partitioning `{1,2,3,4}` using only `[ {3, 4}, {1}, {2, 3}, {4}, {3} ]`.

To see how to solve these smaller problems refer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770068/find-all-partitions-from-a-list-of-subsets).

Comment: Of course, to solve the first option, you need to first remove any sets whose intersection with `{1, 2}` is nonempty before the recursive call. For large problems, this also feels like a good candidate for some kind of memoization / dynamic programming to avoid repeated work (when you've come up with different partitions of the same subset and need to partition the rest).

Comment: Thanks! I did feel stupid, while reading this answer. :) Initially, I had thought of doing the first step in this answer (partitions that include {3, 4}), but with a loop on all the subsets (i.e. find all the partitions that contain a particular subset); however, this results in duplicated partitions (like {1}, {2, 3}, {4} and {4}, {2, 3}, {1}). I guess stupidity is sometimes the price to pay when posting a question right after waking up at 5 AM… :)